# how I can create a list from a list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am using python 3 : , what I am trying to do? I have a list of pictures(some of them are the same, but with different names), I want to comparer them, by looping through the list and group the pictures in that are same in a sub list or dictionary,

for example this is the list of the 3000 
`pictures = [ 'A', 'B','D','F',...]`, asumming that after comparing the pictures `'A'` and `'D'` are the same, and `'B'` and ``F'`, I want to create a new list with sublist, like for example

```
new list = [['A','D'],['B','F'],...
```

or

```
mydict={ 'pic1'=['A','D'],'pic2'=['B','F'],...}.
```

In summary I want organize the pictures by grouping them , for those who has different names but are the same in the same group.

Problem that I have found are that my loop it doesnt update the original list removing those that the same and after apending the into a new list, then the next item ,doesnt have to be the same as the prevous one.for the next iteration.

I have tried several methods, but non of them, update the original list(3000 one )
somecatalogue contain 3000 items, this last method give index out of range(k)

```
obj={}
for i in range(len(somecatalogue)):
  while True:
 #create a item for group same picture but different name
 obj['catalogue'+str(i)] = []
 for k in range(len(somecatalogue)):
         imageA = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\"+somecatalogue[i])
         imageB = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\products_images\\"+somecatalogue[k])
         #resizing the pictures height and width
         if imageA.shape[0]*imageA.shape[1] > 0:
           H, W,C = imageA.shape
     # to resize and set the new width and height
           imageB = cv2.resize(imageB, (W,H))
   #compare the picture+color, add it to the list of the dictionary , and remove it from the original
           if(measure.compare_ssim(imageA,imageB,multichannel=True)==1):
              obj['catalogue'+str(i)].append(somecatalogue[k])
              del(somecatalogue[k])
    #dont product more items form the dictionary if the, there is not more item leave to compare     
  if (len(somecatalogue))==0:
       break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pictures = [ 'A', 'B','D','F']
```

*OP: Assuming picture A and D are similar and B and F are similar.*

I have replaced B and F with A and B to make it simple:

```
pictures = [ 'A', 'B','A','B']

from collections import defaultdict

dict_ = defaultdict(list)
for ind, elem in enumerate(pictures):
    dict_[elem].append(elem)

print(list(dict_.values()))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B']]
```